# Error when loading tensorflow.keras: cannot import name 'kullback_leibler_divergence'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tf.keras

The following error occurs when I'm loading the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization

ImportError: cannot import name 'kullback_leibler_divergence' from 'keras.losses' (/Users/alecbueger/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses/__init__.py)
```

I'm running Python on VS code via the anaconda navigator.

Your help is much appreciated

edit:

Solved!

1. updated macos
2. I created a new environment in the anaconda navigator
3. followed the steps in this link: https://github.com/deganza/Install-TensorFlow-on-Mac-M1-GPU/blob/main/Install-TensorFlow-on-Mac-M1-GPU.ipynb

Comment: Can you try to use `from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization`?

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Unfortunately, your code returns the same error.